# C++ Array Subscript Operator Template

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, metaprogramming

After trying to make access to a storage class a little easier, I ended up in a situation that I don't have a lot of knowledge on. And, finding people that are trying to do the same thing as me isn't easy.

What I'm trying to do, is have a class that stores an array of values as strings internally, but allows simple type casting from the user's end. What I had planned on doing is use the array subscript operator to return whichever type they specify through a template. Although, it sounds a lot better than it works in practice. Here's a simple example of what I'm doing, to give you an idea of how it *should* work.

```
class StringList
{
    public:
    template <typename T> 
    T operator[](const int i)
}
```

From there, I would define a few specific templates, and any user could very easily define more if needed. But, the biggest problem with this is, I don't know how to call the subscript operator with a template. At first I assumed the following(which apparently isn't correct), considering it's similar to the standard way of calling a template method.

```
StringList list;
T var = list<T>[0];
```

Does anyone know the proper way of calling the subscript operator as a template? Or, should I just avoid doing this, and use a named method?

Comment: I would caution against overloading `operator[]` for this purpose as overloaded operators are best used for when they're syntactically meaningful.  You don't normally write thing like `list<T>[0]`, and I think the extra intellectual overhead is not worth it.  Why not just make a template `get` method and call `list.get<int>(0)`?

Comment: @templatetypedef I agree completely. I was more than likely going to just stick with a named function like get, considering I don't even understand how you would write a template like this. But, I am curious to find out how it would be written, regardless of whether or not I ever need to use it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only way calling your operator is explicitly writing `list.operator[]<T>()`.

There are two basic ways out:

1. Write a function template like `list.get<int>()` (as proposed by templatetypedef)
2. Return a proxy with automatic conversation to `T`.

The code would look like:

```
// in the class
struct proxy {
  proxy(StringList *list, int i) : list(list), i(i) {}
  StringList *list;
  int i;
  template <typename T>
  operator T() { return list->get<T>(i); }
};

proxy operator[](int i) { return proxy(this, i); }

template <typename T> 
T get(int i) { return ...; T(); }

// how to use it:
StringList list;
int var = list.get<int>(0);
float var2 = list[0];
```

Comment: I must admit that I don't quite understand your proxy-based solution. Would you mind elaborating a bit? What is the purpose of `T get(int i) { return ...; T(); }`? How is `proxy operator[](int i) { return proxy(this, i); }` related to `StringList`? How does the line `float var2 = list[0];` work? My rather little knowledge of advanced C++ techniques may be the reason here though. :-)

Answer (score 5):

I think there is no syntax to pass template parameters to the natural call of operator[]. You would probably need to call:

```
T var = list.operator[]<T>(0);
```

Like you do with normal template functions, so there is no point in using operator overload here.