# How do I get the template type of a given element at runtime in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I'm designing a simple `Array` class with the capability of holding any type of object, like a vector that can hold multiple types of data in one object. (This is for learning purposes.)

I have an empty base class called `Container`:

```
class Container {};
```

And a templatized subclass called `Object`:

```
template <class T>
class Object : public Container {
    T& object;
public:
    Object(T& obj = nullptr) : object(obj) {}
};
```

I have an `Array` class which holds a `vector` of pointers to `Container`s which I use to hold `Object`s:

```
class Array {
    std::vector<Container *> vec;
public:
    template <class T>
    void add_element(const T&);
    auto get_element(int);
};
```

`add_element` stores elements into `Object`s and puts them into `vec`:

```
template <class T>
void Array::add_element(const T& element)
{
    vec.push_back(new Object<T>(element));
}
```

`get_element` removes the element from it's `Object` and passes it back to the caller. This is where my problem lies. In order to remove the element from the `Object`, I need to know what type of `Object` it is:

```
auto Array::get_element(int i)
{
    return (Object</* ??? */> *)vec[i])->object;
}
```

Is there some way for me to find out what sort of object I'm storing?

**Edit:** since people are claiming that this is not possible, how about this. Is there some way of actually storing type information inside of a class? (I know you can do that in ruby). If I could do that, I could store the return type of `get_element` in each `Object`.

Comment: @ildjarn: Since the OP is using `auto` in the question, I think it's safe to assume that.

Comment: @user315052 because It'd be harder to use that way. @ildjarn Yes it does, but if I `decltype(vec[i])` I'll just get a `Container *`. I need to know what subclass it is.

Comment: Go have a look at [boost::any](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988939/how-do-boostvariant-and-boostany-work)

Comment: @MichaelDorst Edit: since people are claiming that this is not possible, how about this. Is there some way of actually storing type information inside of a class? (I know you can do that in ruby). If I could do that, I could store the return type of get_element in each Object.

In class Object you can save template parameter by typedef, e.g. typedef T object_type; but it can`t help you.

Comment: @ForEveR how is that storing type information? that will only work once (you can't typedef multiple types to the same identifier e.g. `typedef T obj_type; ... typedef Q obj_type;`) and I need it to work for every element I add to my `Array`.

Comment: @ForEveR Also, I don't think you can `typedef` inside of a function. `typedef` is a compile-time thing.

Comment: Each instantiation of template class with different type have own fiels, so, for Object<std::string> object_type will be std::string, for Object<int> object_type will be int etc, also we can declare static variable of such type, but i can`t understood how it can helps you... There is no Reflection in standart C++, so, only RTTI rest.

Comment: @ForEveR So what is the syntax for storing types as variables? It can't be `typedef` can it? I thought `typedef` defined a new type not a variable...

Comment: @MichaelDorst: you *can't* store types as variables.

Comment: May I ask why you are using `nullptr` as the default value of the `obj` parameter in `Object`'s constructor? When you don't provide any argument to the constructor, this is going to fail, isn't it?

Comment: @mfontanini This shouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was thinking something along the lines of this template for your `get_element`.

```
template <class T>
T& Array::get_element(int i, T &t)
{
    Object<T> *o = dynamic_cast<Object<T> *>(vec[i]);
    if (o == 0) throw std::invalid_argument;
    return t = o->object;
}

Array arr;
double f;
int c;

arr.get_element(0, f);
arr.get_element(1, c);
```

But alternatively, you could use this:

```
template <class T>
T& Array::get_element(int i)
{
    Object<T> *o = dynamic_cast<Object<T> *>(vec[i]);
    if (o == 0) throw std::invalid_argument;
    return o->object;
}

f = arr.get_element<double>(0);
c = arr.get_element<int>(1);
```

Comment: I don't really like your throw statement, generally I would throw a `std::exception`, but your basic idea is good. No prb - thx =)

Comment: @MichaelDorst: Edit made, regards

Comment: @MichaelDorst: I saw your edit suggestion. So you are okay with users of your `Array` to call it like `double f = arr.get_element<double>(i)`? Because, I thought `arr.get_element(i, f)` was nicer.

Comment: well then I would have to make a dummy variable every time I called it. That seems silly. better to just specify the type.

Comment: also, I will be overloading `operator []` later, so I'll want the call to be `vec<double>[i];` not `vec[i, f];`. I'm actually not sure if the latter is possible. It's also more clear that I'm casting to `double` if I use it that way.

Comment: @MichaelDorst: Gotcha. Happy hacking!

Comment: @MichaelDorst: when you implement your `operator []`, use the technique described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957936/c-array-subscript-operator-template).

Answer (score 1):

The return type of a function like `Array::get_element` must be determined at compile time.  Since class `Array` does not know what types of containers it stores at compile time, the only option is to just return the base `Container*` pointer.  Then users of that code can use virtual functions and/or `dynamic_cast` to deal with those generalized containers.

Comment: The whole point of this class was so that I wouldn't have to use all that syntax every time I want to access an element. `((Object<Type> *)vec[num].->object` is just too messy.

Comment: If `Container` has enough virtual functions, you don't need any casts.

Answer (score 1):

dynamic_cast<>(), when used on a pointer, can be used to check whether the cast is actually possible since it returns NULL when the types don't match.

However, you'll probably want to reconsider your setup; dynamic_cast isn't something you'll want to use if you can avoid it, and having cascades of "if object-is-type1 then do this; else if object-is-type2 then do that; else if object-is-type3..." is almost always a sure sign of bad design.

Using auto in your get_element is probably your trick of getting around the problem that you don't know what the type will be -- that won't work, though. The compiler still has to know the return type; it cannot change at runtime.

EDIT: you might also go a step back and ask yourself whether you REALLY need an array that can store "anything". I've used Objective-C for a long time, and it's basically built around the idea that everything is just an "object" and people can call anything on anything, it's all sorted out at runtime. However, I found that actual uses of this are rare... and for containers in particular, I find that every NSArray that I use only has objects of one type, or maybe of a common base class, but not actually distinct, unrelated classes.

Comment: The uses are rare, but it's still necessary to have that capability. My original idea was to make a class that I could use as a wrapper around Obj-C objects (to minimize Obj-C++ code since it's hard to maintain). If I use a vector I can't handle every scenario, which is problematic.