# error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'int&' from expression of type 'const int'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

This is an unrelated question about the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370340/how-do-i-get-the-template-type-of-a-given-element-at-runtime-in-c), regarding the following template function.

```
template <class T>
class Object : public Container {
public:
    T& object;

    Object(const T& obj) : object(obj) {}
};
```

This is the code that calls the constructor:

```
template <class T>
void Array::add_element(const T& element)
{
    vec.push_back(new Object<T>(element));
}
```

This code compiles fine, but as soon as I add a line in `main` that calls it:

```
Array array;
int i = 3;
array.add_element(i);
```

I get a compiler warning: `error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'int&' from expression of type 'const int'`.

What is that about? I passed an `int` in. Shouldn't it automatically be turned into a `const int&` for me? Why is the compiler complaining?

Comment: Hint: `T& object;` -- Also, `const T& obj = nullptr` doesn't make any sense, you can't initialize a reference to a `nullptr`.

Comment: How is that a hint? That's exactly how `object` is already declared. And thank you, I will change that.

Comment: It's a hint because you can't initialize a non-const reference from a const reference -- const-correctness 101.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`obj` is a const reference. `object` is a non-const reference.

You can't initialize a non-const reference from a const reference, because doing so would defeat the purpose of having a const reference in the first place.

If you want your instance of `Object` to be able to modify the `int` that's passed to its constructor, then the constructor should take a non-const reference. If you don't, then the data member should be a const reference.

In any case, you are storing up trouble for yourself if you use `new` to allocate objects that have references as data members. It's *your* problem to ensure that you delete the `Object` before `i` goes out of scope (or anyway, ensure that the `Object` doesn't use its member `object` after `i` goes out of scope.

Answer (score 12):

You are trying to assign a const reference to a non const reference.
This means that your Object class can modify the content of object.

```
const int myConstNumber = 4;
Object<int> intObj(myConstNumber);

intObj.object = 3; // you have indirectly modified the value of myConstNumber
```

C++ doesn't let you do that.
You can make a copy of the object or add the const to your attribute.

```
template <class T>
class Object : public Container {
public:
    T object; // valid
```

or

```
template <class T>
class Object : public Container {
public:
    const T& object; // valid
```

in this case you won't be able to modify object

Comment: Thanks, your answer is also good, but first-come first-serve, sorry =/

Comment: It's ok, I'm here to help, not for the kudos. :)