# C++ wrapper class that stores an arbitrary reference, but itself is not a class template

Tags: c++, c++11, wrapper

Is it possible to define a class which is not a class template and that can store (say upon construction) a reference to any particular type and retrieve it later via a getter method?

```
struct Wrapper {
  template<typename T> Wrapper(const T& t): t_(t);

  // How to store the reference??
};
```

`Boost::variant` is of course not a solution since its implemented as a class template. And I have no RTTI. (Its in HPC environment, performance is all!)

The `getter()` should be able to remember the type. So that `auto` can be used later.

Comment: Can't you use a pointer?

Comment: At the end I want to store instances of `std::function<T0 (T1,T2)>` with unpredictable `T0`, `T1`, `T2`

Comment: `std::function<T0 (T1,T2)>` is a template.

Comment: You can look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11370340/315052) for an idea.

Comment: How would you *use* the reference?

Comment: When looking at `boost::variant`, why didn't you find his dynamic non-template brother `boost::any`?

Comment: Right, dynamic overhead is not ideal.

Comment: @KerrekSB I would push instances of `Wrapper` on a stack (order resembles mathematical order) and execute the functions. I need a `Wrapper` to have simple return types of `operator+` like functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The getter() should be able to remember the type.

It can't. You *erased* the type. That's what happens when you put a value of arbitrary type inside an object of a consistent type. It's called "type erasure": the original type is *removed* from the containing class.

One of the consequences of this is that the type cannot magically be recovered. You can't have a class that is initialized with a type on a per-instance basis, and then have one of its member functions return a different type based on how that particular instance was initialized.

C++ is a *statically* typed language. The return type of every function must be defined at compile time. It cannot change because of what you put into a class at runtime.

> It can't remember the type.
>
> I can't use RTTI.

Then what you want is a `void*`. RTTI is the only way to do recover the original value's type in a type-safe way. If you don't want type-safety, then you want a `void*`. All you would be doing is writing a wrapper around `static_cast<T*>`.

There's really no point in writing a wrapper around `void*` and `static_cast`. If that's what you want, and you're willing to accept the perils of using them (ie: breaking the type-system), then just use it. The reason `boost::any` exists is to provide a type-*safe* `void*`, so that at least you know when you're casting it wrongly.

Answer (score 3):

`boost::any` http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/any.html

```
std::vector<boost::any> many;
int i = 5;
std::string a = "5";

many.push_back(i);
many.push_back(a);

std::string res;
if (many[1].type() == typeid(std::string))
  res = boost::any_cast<std::string>(many[1]);
```

Comment: Well anyhow you have to remember the type of what you are putting in your wrapper. Either you store its RTTI like with boost any, either you are using a union and remember which representation is correct like with boost variant... But maybe we are missing your real problem. You said you want a simple return type to `operator+`. What is the problem exactly ?

Comment: @Frank Note that the cost of using typeid is light in c++. It is a constant time operation if the type is polymorphic, and has no cost if the real type can be deduced directly or indirectly at compile time. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid